# Is there a way to attach a file generated in excection to the result with Tricentis Tosca TBoxAPI

Tags: automation, tosca

is it possible to attach a file that gets generated in execution of the testcase to the execution result in Tricentis Tosca?

I wrote a SpecialExecutionTask that generates a .csv file, but now I want to attach it to the TestResult so I have it in the project.

Is there any way with the TBox API to do that?

Thanks